# Make Jupyter notebook executable in html format

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, android-binder

I'm trying to export a Jupyter notebook in HTML, obtaining an executable version of it. Until now, my approach is to upload the notebook in a git repository and then using binder to obtain its executable version. I would like to upload the notebook on my webpage without passing also the link of the binder project. Is that possible ?

I read about nbinteract and saw tutorials about making dynamic widgets, but here I'm trying to make dynamic the whole code in the notebook.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `jupyter` need a server to execute the python code.

If you want to execute some python code (or your notebooks) in the browser you can have a look to https://github.com/gzuidhof/starboard-notebook or https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide .

an extract from the `pyodide` doc:

> Pyodide brings the Python 3.8 runtime to the browser via WebAssembly,
> along with the Python scientific stack including NumPy, Pandas,
> Matplotlib, SciPy, and scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I have a sinology NAS with jupyter server installed on it. Also my website uses the same NAS. Also in this situation is not possible to integrate them ? I would like to obtain something similar to the textbook shows in this website https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/multiple-qubits-entangled-states.html

Comment: Yes, you can have a look to voila. https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can execute code from code cells in an HTML page using Jupyter kernels:

1. Use [thebelab.js](https://thebelab.readthedocs.io/): this Javascript package allows you to launch a remote MyBinder kernel or connect to a pre-existing Jupyter server and then send code from the HTML page to the remote kernel. The remote kernel executes the code, and returns the response / code output to the HTML page, which can then render it. Outputs can include HTML widgets.
2. Use [`nbinteract`](https://www.nbinteract.com/) to create an HTML page from a notebook that can execute code on a remote MyBinder server to power interactive `ipywidgets` within the HTML page.
3. Generate an interactive HTML textbook/documentation site using [`jupyter-book`](https://jupyterbook.org/intro.html) that has been configured to execute code against a remote kernel started and managed using `thebelab.js`.

You can also use [`jupyterlite`](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/): `jupyterlite` is an in-browser implementation of JupyterLab and RetroLab UIs that runs completely in the browser. Code is executed against a WASM implemented kernel. *Currently Python (pyodide), Javascript and p5 kernels are available.*